# ElasticSearch escape special character

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

How I escape Unicode characters using a query_string query? For example, my documents consist of the following data:

```
{
    "title":"Sachin$tendular"
     }
```

I am using the query_string query in the following way:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["title"],
      "query": "*Sachin$*"
    }
  }
}
```

but it is not giving me any result and if I removed $ from the query it works

SO how we can handle $ here?

Hi my title field mapping is

```
"title" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

Whem I  using query like

```
[{
    "query_string": {
         "query": "*character*",
           "fields": ["title.raw"],
            "default_operator": "OR"
     }
 }]
```

It works but when I am using query like

```
[{
        "query_string": {
             "query": "*Special character*",
               "fields": ["title.raw"],
                "default_operator": "OR"
         }
     }]
```

it not works  but

```
[{
            "query_string": {
                 "query": "*Special character*",
                   "fields": ["title"],
                    "default_operator": "OR"
             }
         }]
```

it works and my Title data like this:

```
Special character test ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + - = { } [ ] | \\ ; : \" ' < > , . / ? ~ ` ₹
```

SO how I can get all combination result here using a single query? and when to use title and title.raw here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `title` field is of `text` type, so elasticsearch uses standard analyzer if no analyzer is defined for `text` type field. `Sachin$tendular` gets tokenized to

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "sachin",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "tendular",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use query string on `title.keyword` field if you are using the default mapping. This will use a keyword analyzer, instead of the standard analyzer. Otherwise, change the data type of the `title` field to that of `keyword` type

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["title.keyword"],
      "query": "*Sachin$*"
    }
  }
}
```

**Otherwise, you can [update your field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex), use multi fields for the `title` field, as shown in the documentation.**

**Update 1:**

You can use a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) instead to search for wildcard expression with spaces

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "title.keyword": {
        "value": "*Special character*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks How we can use this in nested fields?

Comment: @SurajDalvi which nested fields are you asking about ?

Comment: update the question with title field mapping can you please check it and let me know

Comment: basically, I want to use contain query here. Means I want those title whose contain given value. either full value or partial value

Comment: @SurajDalvi updated the answer, please go through the updated part, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I have checked this but sorry it is not working have you checked my title mapping? and also what if I want to search like this ! @  or only want to search ! how I can do this?

Comment: is any direct option that I can use for contains query?

Comment: is any query present in ES for contains with  OR means I want those documents whose title contains ! or @  or any combination.

Comment: if it is not possible in Elastic search  then please let me know